# Can we guarantee a solution to the system $b = x^T Z - Z x$ ? (w.r.t. $Z$)

Tags: linear-algebra, applications

**Question:** Can we guarantee a solution to this system?

---

I have a system of compartments as shown in the Figure (for $N=3$).

The mass flow among the compartments can be described by

$$
\frac{d}{dt}x_{i} =
\sum_{j}Z_{ji} \thinspace x_{j} -
\sum_{j}Z_{ij} \thinspace x_{i}
$$

`< edit: not relevant and maybe incorrect, please ignore >`

or, for the entire system ($\mathbf{x} = [x_1,x_2,x_3]$), $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{x} = {(\mathbf{x}^T Z)}^{T} - Z \mathbf{x}$

`< / edit >`

**Goal:** We want to solve for $Z$, knowing the values of the two vectors (i) $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, and (ii) $\mathbf{x}$.

**Approach:** If we define a vector $\mathbf{z} = \mathrm{vec}(Z)$, then we can factor the RHS of the above to a linear system like:

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}
&= A \thinspace \mathbf{z} \\
&\quad \textrm{(e.g. for $N=2$)}\\
&=
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\cdot & -x_1  &  x_2  & \cdot \\
\cdot &  x_1  & -x_2  & \cdot
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
Z_{11} \\ Z_{12} \\
Z_{21} \\ Z_{22}
\end{array}\right] \\
&\quad \textrm{(e.g. for $N=3$)}\\
&=
\left[\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
\cdot & -x_1  & -x_1  &  x_2  & \cdot & \cdot &  x_3  & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot &  x_1  & \cdot & -x_2  & \cdot & -x_2  & \cdot &  x_3  & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot &  x_1  & \cdot & \cdot &  x_2  & -x_3  & -x_3  & \cdot 
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
Z_{11} \\ Z_{12} \\ Z_{13} \\
Z_{21} \\ Z_{22} \\ Z_{23} \\
Z_{31} \\ Z_{32} \\ Z_{33}
\end{array}\right]
\end{align}

Then, we can solve for $\mathbf{z}$ using the usual methods. The diagonal elements will be undefined, but that's fine as they are irrelevant to the compartment flows (in my case).

**Specific Questions:**

- It seems $A$ is always Rank $N-1$; is this true? Why?
- For any choice of $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{x} \implies A$, can we guarantee a solution $\mathbf{z} \implies Z$?
- If not, can we derive constraints on $\mathbf{b}$ and / or $\mathbf{x}$ to guarantee a solution?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Does $x^TA-Ax$ makes sense at all? If $x$ is a $1\times 3$ row, then $A$ must be $3\times n$; but then $Ax$ should be defined, so $n=1$. However you cannot sum a $1\times1$ matrix with a $3\times3$ one.

Comment: This doesn't seem to follow from the previous equation: $$\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}^T Z - Z \mathbf{x}
$$

Comment: Maybe you meant $Z^T x$?

Comment: In matrix form, the original equation should be $\dot{\mathbf x}=Z^T\mathbf x - \operatorname{diag}(Z\mathbf e)\mathbf x=Z^T\mathbf x - \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf x)Z\mathbf e$, where $\mathbf e$ is the all-one vector. So, if you put $Y= \operatorname{diag}(\mathbf x)Z$, the equation you want to solve should be (provided that $\mathbf x$ is entrywise nonzero) $\mathbf b=(Y^T-Y)\mathbf e$.

Comment: It seems my transformation to matrix form is not correct (see `edit`). However, the definition of $A$ in **Approach** should still follow from the very first equation with sums.

Comment: @egreg, $Z$ (I think you mean, not $A$) is square by definition in this case. I think the problem is that the first term should be transposed again, yielding $(x^T Z)^T - Z x$, which should be $N \times 1$ for both terms, and the same shape as $b$.

Comment: @JesseKnight You wrote $A$ in the title. If it is $(x^TZ)^T-Zx$, then it simpler writing it as $(Z^T-Z)x=0$, isn't it? Of course, any symmetric matrix is a solution.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, fixed the title issue (changed notation while writing question...). Re: $(Z^T - Z)x = 0$, yes! That's progress.  However, what changes about having symmetric $Z$ as a solution when RHS is $b \ne 0$?